BuildConfig issue in Android Studio Ladybug
I'm using Android Studio Ladybug Canary 9. I've defined buildConfigField in my build.gradle.kts file, but the BuildConfig class is not being generated. I'm getting an 'unresolved reference' error. What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?
I tried with a minimal setup project still not working..
build.gradle(Module:app)
android {
    namespace = "com.example.testbuildconfig"
    compileSdk = 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.testbuildconfig"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 35
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"FAKE_KEY_123\"")
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        buildConfig = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.8"
    }
}

when I try to import BuildConfig or access buildConfig.API_KEY i get an unresolved reference error

In the stable version of the IDE this works without problems.

try to click "make project" on Android Studio toolbar

ruby6221 "make project" worked thank you !

It could be possibly the Android Studio Version you are using.
I would recommend you to use the stable version of the Android Ladybug. Currently I'm using Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 and facing no such issue.
